# Создать массив без пропусков

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужен массив такого плана `option[product_option_id] = product_option_value_id;`

Пытался сделать вот так:

```
var p_option = [];
p_option[product_option_id] = product_option_value_id;
```

Но в таком случае если `product_option_id = 229`, то создается еще 228 пустых значений

[image: пример]

Как сделать что бы не создавались эти пустые значения массива, а только один тот что нужен?

Comment: сделай `p_option[0] = product_option_value_id;`

Comment: не так е годиться product_option_id может быть любым числом

Comment: и что? проблема не ясна....... используй тогда не массив а объект ключ -> значение

Comment: А причём тут многомерные массивы?

Comment: И причём тут jquery?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Больше не причём :)

Comment: _создается еще 228 пустых значений_ - не совсем так. Чем именно не устраивает текущий результат?

Answer (score 0):

Для создания ассоциативного массива используйте фигурные скобки `{}` а не квадратные `[]`:

```
let p_option = {};
let product_option_id = 229;
let product_option_value_id = 'Какое то значение';
p_option[product_option_id] = product_option_value_id;
```

Comment: Круглые скобки - это вот эти: `()`

Comment: И что не так с ответом?

Comment: @stckvrw текст неправильный в ответе

Answer (score -1):

Обычные объекты вам намного больше подойдут, но если хочется именно работать как с массивом, то это можно имитировать с помощью [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

```js
const myObj = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    for (const value of Object.values(this)) {
      yield value;
    }
  }
}

myObj[1] = '1a';
myObj[10] = '10b';
myObj[100] = '100c';

console.log('myObj:', myObj);

for (const value of myObj) {
  console.log('From for of loop', value);
}

const [a, b, c] = myObj;

console.log('After destructuring', a, b, c);
```

Comment: зачем брать ключи и получать значение, если можно сразу получать значения [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: @Grundy Резонно, что-то затупил... Спасибо